# Displaying to HTML with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm really new to NodeJS,
What I'm trying to understand is if there is a way to use NodeJS like JS, I'm trying to grab information from database, and display it inside a div in my index.html.
When I tried to do it by queryselector I received an error, what I have done so far is receiving the data in a new page as JSON.
I have a div in my index.html file which called content-txt, this is the place I put to put the response.
Also, when I try to loop trough the rows, I receive `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

My code so far:
app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
    // Properties
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dyextension'
});

connect.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error) {
        console.log('Could not connect to DB');
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to DB');
    }
});

app.listen(5500, ()=>console.log('Express server is running on port no: 5500'));

// Get all alerts
app.get('/alerts', (req,res)=>{
    connect.query('SELECT * FROM alerts', (err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                res.send(`<div>${rows[i].alert_name}</div>`);

            }
        }
        else
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.3.1/litera/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-D/7uAka7uwterkSxa2LwZR7RJqH2X6jfmhkJ0vFPGUtPyBMF2WMq9S+f9Ik5jJu1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>d</title>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- Content here -->
      <div class="container" id="content-txt">

      </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html
 Start from some basic, it will help to understand better.

Comment: You have include app.js in index.html file and app,js is a node js file. You have to run nodejs file i.e app.js on server then ajax call from front end to hit the api the response will come and use that response to show result on frontend

Answer (score 0):

By design, the HTTP protocol can only return the response once.

The way to do it with your code is to concatenate your results to a variable, and thereafter, return this variable as a response.

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
    // Properties
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dyextension'
});

connect.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error) {
        console.log('Could not connect to DB');
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to DB');
    }
});

app.listen(5500, ()=>console.log('Express server is running on port no: 5500'));

// Get all alerts
app.get('/alerts', (req,res)=>{
    connect.query('SELECT * FROM alerts', (err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            let results;
            for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                results += `<div>${rows[i].alert_name}</div>`;

            }
            return res.send(results);
        }
        else
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```